# iPhone, how what I show smaller views ontop of normal view and switch between my current normal views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'd like to display some small tutorial dialogs on top of my exiting views. I want to be able to see my existing views behind these smaller views.

Do I have to use view controllers in the same I way I would me normal views, and presentmodalviewcontroller etc ?

I haven't tried making a smaller view in interface builder before.

Also, say I want to move to another one of my existing views, full screen, while in my tutorial view. How would I close my tutorial view move to the next full screen view and launch another tutorial view ?

Example code or pseudo code would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tutorial dialogs are just text, you could use UIAlertView to show the information to the user, so they can just read it and click the OK button when they're done.  It's a very easy way to show some text to the user.

If you need to include images or other interactive items in your tutorial dialogs, the easiest way might be for you to just have your fullscreen view's view controller create a new view and put it up.  So in this case, you'd create your view in Interface Builder, and when you want to show it, instantiate it using -[UIBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:] and add it as a subview of your main view.  Of course, it may even be easier to create the tutorial view programmatically from your view controller rather than using a nib for them at all.

Regarding the question of moving on to another fullscreen view, you would probably want to look into embedding your view controllers in a UINavigationController.  This would allow you to push from the first controller to the second very easily, and the user would be able to just tap the Back button to get back to the first.  If you're not looking for a navigation bar type of interface, you could present the second view controller as a modal view controller by calling -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] on your main view controller.  This will pop up the second view controller fullscreen, and the user can dismiss it when they're done.  Check out Apple's great documentation on UINavigationController to get a feel for how to use that:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1

Comment: OK good idea, the only thing is I'm going to be changing navigation controller, I may want to click next in my tutorial dialog. How do I go about calling the new tutorial dialog once the next view is shown ? Hmmm, I guess I could pass a parameter into that view, e.g. call_tutorial.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the navigation controller for your main view by clicking a button in the tutorial view?  If so, just set the target and action of your tutorial view's button to be the view controller that created it.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you could use existing UIViewController and simply add a new UIView that is of desired dimensions, that sits in front of other views and which is non-opaque and has alpha less than 1.

If you want a general purpose tutorial mechanism that can be placed atop any one of many UIViewControllers, then you would want to extract the navigation logic, etc.

Sorry, no code - just a few quick thoughts.